# Monitor multiple nginx-proxy pods with prometheus-nginx-exporter

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an kubernetes installation with nginx-proxy on worker nodes.
It looks like one nginx pod per node deployed by kubespray with manifest: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/roles/kubernetes/node/templates/manifests/nginx-proxy.manifest.j2

```
root@d6422c83-bd13-11e9-aa68-fa163ee27044:~# kubectl -n kube-system get po -l "k8s-app=kube-nginx"
NAME                                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-proxy-d8ffb7c4-bd13-11e9-aa68-fa163ee27044   1/1     Running   1          40h
nginx-proxy-d901b40b-bd13-11e9-aa68-fa163ee27044   1/1     Running   3          40h
nginx-proxy-d9029362-bd13-11e9-aa68-fa163ee27044   1/1     Running   1          40h
```

Nginx exporter requires scrape-uri pointed to exact Nginx service: https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter/blob/master/client/nginx.go#L13
And that exporter is deployed by Helm chart:

The usual solution for such cases is to use sidecar container with the exporter in application pod.

But here we can't do that because nginx-proxy is managed by kubespray/ansible and nginx-exporter is managed by helm chart.

I suppose it should look like: one additional pod with nginx-exporter for each not-master node with `scrape-uri http://127.0.0.1:10800`
So somehow port 10800 should be available from nodes' localhost for nginx-exporter pod.

Any suggestions here?

Comment: If you want a proper answer, paste a verbose question in the slack channel of #kubernetes!

Comment: please share with information about used helm chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using `hostNetwork: true` option for both pods.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly this case - the sidecar was removed.
Please refer to the [github issue](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/3290). 
If I am correct: please enable [metrics controller](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress#prometheus-metrics).

```
metrics:
      enabled: true

|---------------------------|-----------------------------------|---------|
|      Parameter            |    Description                    | Default |
|---------------------------|-----------------------------------|---------|
|controller.metrics.enabled | if true, enable Prometheus metrics|  false  |
|---------------------------|-----------------------------------|---------|
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: That is a different case. Nginx here comes as a part of general k8s installation, not an optional ingress for some service. AFAIU it is required for worker nodes to be able to connect to masters.

Anyway, that was solved by using hostNetwork option for nginx & exporter pods